# regex match only two group

Tags: regex

[image]

I want to receive in example regex match only 17 and 20 (skip 3 match only two match)

Comment: What are the criteria for a match here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, this one can be a good solution

```
[0-9]{2}(?!$)
```

It matches the groups of 2 digits not at the end of a line !

You can also try : `([0-9]{2})\s[A-z]+\s([0-9]{2})` if you want only 2 groups